# How to periodically refresh a view in vaadin?

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I'd like to refresh a certain part of a page periodically. Therefore I created a `@Scheduled` method that applies the changing values accordingly to the widgets.

But the method never executes:

```
@Controller
@UIScope
public class MyViewPresenter {
    private View view;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void refresh() {
        System.out.println("this is never executed. why?");
            //view.change...
    }
}
```

When I move this method into my `@Configuration` class the sysout is printed fine. So in general I can assume the scheduling works as expected. But not in my presenter class. Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32249435/vaadin-7-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-refresh-a-vaadin-view-in-5-minute-interval

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51794618/vaadin-8-reload-grid-with-data-from-server-every-1min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable server push feature [11.16. Server Push](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.push.html)

In short:

- add `vaadin-push` library to your dependecies
- enable pushing (`@Push` annotation or servlet configuration)
- use `UI.access(..)` for pushing

Comment: You could be a bit more specific