# VAADIN 7: What is the simplest way to refresh a Vaadin View in 5 minute intervals?

Tags: java, events, refresh, polling, vaadin7

I'm trying to implement an automatic refresh on a List of components in a Vaadin view. The list gets its contents from a database. I can refresh the list with a button, that is already implemented.

However, I would like to know what is the simplest way to make it so, that this refresh event, that I already have, would automatically refresh in 5 minute (300 000 milliseconds) intervals?

Here's what I tried and it keeps refreshing even after I exit the view so it doesn't really work. **I'd like the refresh to happen in 5 minute intervals only while that certain view is being shown.**

```
UI myUI = UI.getCurrent();  

            myUI.setPollInterval(300000);
            myUI.addPollListener(event -> {
                refreshList();
            });
```

How would I make it so that the refresh doesn't happen after navigating to other views? And is there some simpler way to do this in Vaadin? Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51794618/vaadin-8-reload-grid-with-data-from-server-every-1min

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do so that you call

```
myUI.setPollInterval(300000);
```

when the view is activated, and you disable it by calling

```
myUI.setPollInterval(-1);
```

when another view is activated. If you use Vaadin Navigator, then you could use `ViewChangeListener` for handling the polling.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that tomorrow and come back to your answer. We are using Vaadin Navigator.

Comment: Does `setPollInterval()` work globally or locally? Does `setPollInterval` set this for all session?

Comment: @jsosnowski per connector object.